# awk + simple example + output not as expected + sum and count values in a file

Tags: awk

This is my file:

```
$ cat inventory-shipped
Jan 13 25 15 115
Feb 15 32 24 226
Mar 15 24 34 228
Apr 31 52 63 420
May 16 34 29 208
Jun 31 42 75 492
Jul 24 34 67 436
Aug 15 34 47 316
Sep 13 55 37 277
Oct 29 54 68 525
Nov 20 87 82 577
Dec 17 35 61 401
Jan 21 36 64 620
Feb 26 58 80 652
Mar 24 75 70 495
Apr 21 70 74 514
```

This is what I want to achieve: (it matches anything in column1 with '/Dec/' , it counts this occurance, and it sums column 2 based on this occurance)

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /Dec/ {count++; sum+=$2} END {printf ("Dec" FS count FS sum)}' inventory-shipped
Dec 1 17
```

This is my attempt where I store the value `Dec`, above in a variable j `$ echo "$j" ##Dec`. So I would expect the same output as I have above `Dec 1 17`, that is 3 fields, but here I am just getting `Dec`, that is 1 field.

```
$ awk -v k="$j" '$1 ~ /k/ {count++; sum+=$2} END {printf ("%s" FS count FS sum,k)}' inventory-shipped
Dec
```

This is my second attempt:

```
$ awk -v k="$j" '$1 ~ /k/ {count++; sum+=$2} END {printf (k FS count FS sum)}' inventory-shipped
Dec
```

but it is not printing the sum or count values that I want. **Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong**

---

### EDIT1

tks to @Ed's answer below this is what I want:

```
$ j="Dec"

$ echo "$j"
Dec

//this gives me what i want if I use the equals comparison operation
$ awk -v k="$j" '$1 == k{count++; sum+=$2} END{print k, count+0, sum+0}' inventory-shipped
Dec 1 17
```

But what if I want to use regex comparison operationm, how would I write it? I am assuming I would get the same result, but I just want to know how to get the regex to work. this is my attempt:

```
$ awk -v k="$j" '$1 ~ /k/{count++; sum+=$2} END{print k, count+0, sum+0}' inventory-shipped
Dec 0 0
```

Comment: tks, have tried to explain it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were trying to use a variable within a [regexp constant](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Constants). You don't need/want a regexp comparison for this anyway though, just a string comparison:

```
awk -v k="$j" '$1 == k{count++; sum+=$2} END{print k, count+0, sum+0}' inventory-shipped
```

The `+0`s are so you get numeric output even with an empty file.

Here's the basic syntax to comparing strings and regexps with awk:

- String Comparison using a constant string: `$0 == "foo"`
- String Comparison using a string in a variable: `{myvar="foo"} $0 == myvar`
- [Regexp Constant](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Using-Constant-Regexps) Comparison: `$0 ~ /foo/`
- [Dynamic Regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps) Comparison using a constant string: `$0 ~ "foo"`
- [Dynamic Regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps) Comparison using a string in a variable: `{myvar="foo"} $0 ~ myvar`

One important difference between Regexp Constants and Dynamic Regexps is that the latter gets parsed twice, the first time to turn the string into a regexp and the second when it's being evaluated as a regexp. So the equivalent of the Regexp Constant comparison `$0 ~ /a\tb/` would be `$0 ~ "a\\tb"` with a Dynamic Regexp since a single escape character would get used up by the string->regexp conversion.

So the general rule to avoid gotchas is - always use Regexp Constants wherever possible, and only use Dynamic Regexps when you need them, e.g. to concatenate a string with a variable before comparison. That rule applies to function arguments like *sub(), split(), and match() too, not just comparison operators.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp for more info on using regexps.

Comment: tks see my EDIT1 in Q. What if I want to use regex comparison operationm, how would I write it?

Comment: Then `k` would contain a [dynamic regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps) so `$1 ~ k`. I edited my question to show the various flavors of string and regexp comparisons.

Comment: tk u very much, greatly appreciated!